# fix the item's z-index in IE8

Tags: html, css, iframe, alert

I have this css code : 
http://lawb.co.il/style.css

Which I use it for this site http://nave.net23.net

As you can see in google chrom, firefox, IE9 it works great, the problem is that when  I open this site in IE8 or IE7  the whole form which is in iframe tag and in IE8 the form is cover the slidshow image and the main pargraph.
If I change the iframe z-index style to a zero  the elert which should be shown when someone isn't complete all the field in the form correctly, in 'under' the slidshow insted above it...
can you help me fix it so the alert will be above the text and the slidshow and the iframe tag will be under them at the same time?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE, iframes backgrounds don't resort to a transparent color by default, you have to supply the `allowTransparency="true"` attribute to the iframe for that to happen.

Comment: Thank you!!! the now problem is that the alert's form is under the image and under the text, ehat can I do to make the alrts only above all the other divs?
Here is an example to the problen. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7zzgygpsqcn5ob/1.png
thank you veru much!

Comment: @NaveTseva can't test for that but one thing you can try is removing the z-index from the image itself, or adding a really high index to the iframe container.

Comment: I added a high index for the iframe, now it works grat, thank you very much!!

Comment: @NaveTseva awesome, i'm glad i was of help.